# Call Julia from Python using pyjulia not multithreading

Tags: python, julia

When I run julia 0.3.2 or 0.5 as standalone
(mix model), it uses all the available cores from my server, so it was fast. (3M records 800 sec)

```
j = julia.Julia()
juliaCode = ""
calcLME = j.eval(juliaCode)
result = calcLME(inputData)
```

If I call Julia from Python with pyjulia, I see only one core is busy with
python process (100% cpu) and all other cores are free. How can I force pyjulia/python to use all of the available cores of my server?

Comment: If you are calling addprocs in the pure-Julia version, you need to do the same from pyjulia.

In other words, nprocs() in pure Julia must match j.nprocs() in pyjulia.

Comment: You should really upgrade from 0.3.2; that's a very old version.

Comment: also, your question does not elaborate on the nature of your parallel calculations. do you manually add and schedule the cores? also, heed Fengyang Wang's comment; Julia 0.3.2 is no longer maintained, and its successors have undergone heavy redevelopment.

Comment: We are upgrading to V0.5, but there is some trouble with py julia and rectifying it. i will check and get back here. One question if i pass formula in the command line ` julia test.jl col~coln2+col3` how can i convert arg[1] in in lmm  `lmm(args[1], df)`.. its complaining ERROR: `lmm` has no method matching lmm(::UTF8String, ::DataFrame)