# How to add processors (addprocs) for Pyjulia 0.5.2 and return the value of Julia function to Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, julia

Does anyone know how to add processors for Pyjulia when calling Julia function in Python? I need to use Python to call a Julia function using multiple cores and return values to Python.

The Python code, `testJulia_addproc.py`:

```
import julia
j = julia.Julia()
print("Core number = {}".format(j.nprocs()))
j.include("test_addproc.jl")
a = j.eval("test_addproc()")
print a
```

The Julia code `test_addproc.jl`:

```
function test_addproc()
    println("line 1")
    np = nprocs()
    println("line 2")
    if np < 12
        println("line 3")
        addprocs(12-np)
        println("line 4")
    end
    println("line 5")
    return(1+1)
end
```

==
`$ python testJulia_addproc.py`
I got this error.

```
WARNING: redefining constant JULIA_HOME
Core number = 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
ERROR (unhandled task failure): could not spawn setenv(`/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/../fake-julia/julia -Ccore2 -J/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --bind-to 127.0.0.1 --worker pjVTa5WBhFbDB7vs`; dir="/Users/chlin/Dropbox/Projects/StackOverflow"): no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn(::String, ::Array{String,1}, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Base.Process, ::Base.DevNullStream, ::Base.PipeEndpoint, ::Base.TTY) at ./process.jl:321
 in #424 at ./process.jl:478 [inlined]
 in setup_stdio(::Base.##424#425{Cmd,Ptr{Void},Base.Process}, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}) at ./process.jl:466
 in #spawn#423(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./process.jl:477
 in (::Base.#kw##spawn)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#spawn, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
 in #spawn#420(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Base.CmdRedirect, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./process.jl:359
 in (::Base.#kw##spawn)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#spawn, ::Base.CmdRedirect, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
 in open(::Base.CmdRedirect, ::String, ::Base.DevNullStream) at ./process.jl:539
 in launch(::Base.LocalManager, ::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Array{WorkerConfig,1}, ::Condition) at ./managers.jl:318
 in (::Base.##666#670{Base.LocalManager,Dict{Any,Any},Array{WorkerConfig,1},Condition})() at ./event.jl:68
could not spawn setenv(`/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/../fake-julia/julia -Ccore2 -J/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --bind-to 127.0.0.1 --worker pjVTa5WBhFbDB7vs`; dir="/Users/chlin/Dropbox/Projects/StackOverflow"): no such file or directory (ENOENT)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testJulia_addproc.py", line 5, in <module>
    j.eval("test_addproc()")
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/core.py", line 436, in eval
    ans = self._call(src)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/core.py", line 399, in _call
    self.check_exception(src)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/core.py", line 419, in check_exception
    .format(exception_type, src))
julia.core.JuliaError: Exception 'UVError' occurred while calling julia code:
test_addproc()
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753568/call-julia-from-python-using-pyjulia-not-multithreading), I found the number of processors in pyjulia needs to match the number in Julia (@Isaiah: `nprocs()` in pure Julia must match `j.nprocs()`).

I tried to add procs in pyjulia.

```
import julia
j = julia.Julia()
j.addprocs(2)
```

Got errors:

```
ERROR (unhandled task failure): could not spawn setenv(`/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/../fake-julia/julia -Ccore2 -J/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --bind-to 127.0.0.1 --worker 8WpA7O0EArLzXh25`; dir="/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin"): no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn(::String, ::Array{String,1}, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Base.Process, ::Base.DevNullStream, ::Base.PipeEndpoint, ::Base.TTY) at ./process.jl:321
 in #424 at ./process.jl:478 [inlined]
 in setup_stdio(::Base.##424#425{Cmd,Ptr{Void},Base.Process}, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}) at ./process.jl:466
 in #spawn#423(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./process.jl:477
 in (::Base.#kw##spawn)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#spawn, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
 in #spawn#420(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Base.CmdRedirect, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./process.jl:359
 in (::Base.#kw##spawn)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#spawn, ::Base.CmdRedirect, ::Tuple{Base.DevNullStream,Pipe,Base.TTY}, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./<missing>:0
 in open(::Base.CmdRedirect, ::String, ::Base.DevNullStream) at ./process.jl:539
 in launch(::Base.LocalManager, ::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Array{WorkerConfig,1}, ::Condition) at ./managers.jl:318
 in (::Base.##666#670{Base.LocalManager,Dict{Any,Any},Array{WorkerConfig,1},Condition})() at ./event.jl:68
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bfa063d91dec> in <module>()
----> 1 j.addprocs(2)

RuntimeError: Julia exception: could not spawn setenv(`/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/../fake-julia/julia -Ccore2 -J/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --bind-to 127.0.0.1 --worker 8WpA7O0EArLzXh25`; dir="/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin"): no such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

Based on [this post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-call-from-python3-running-in-single-core/508), I found there is a way around to add processors in pyjulia, but didn't return values of the Julia function.

```
# One way to add procs in pyjulia
import ctypes
JLPATH=b"/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia"
jl = ctypes.PyDLL(JLPATH+b"/lib/libjulia.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
jl.jl_init(JLPATH+b"/bin/")
jl.jl_eval_string(" include(test_addproc.jl) ")
a = jl.jl_eval_string(" test_addproc()) ")
print a
# 0
# It should be 2
```

My MacPro version is `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5`
My Python version is `Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)`.
My Julia version is

```
Julia Version 0.5.2
Commit f4c6c9d4bb (2017-05-06 16:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.7.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

Any suggestion or thought are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first error message says,

`` ERROR (unhandled task failure): could not spawn setenv(`/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/julia/../fake-julia/julia -Ccore2 -J/Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --bind-to 127.0.0.1 --worker pjVTa5WBhFbDB7vs`; dir="/Users/chlin/Dropbox/Projects/StackOverflow"): no such file or directory (ENOENT) ``

I found there is no `fake-julia` directory in the python package folder.
So I copied `fake-julia` directory to `/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/julia-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/` from [PyJulia](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia).
Now I am able to add processor by `j.addprocs(1)` and get result `2` from `testJulia_addproc.py` without error.

So far that's a way around it.
I am also posting issues on PyJulia GitHub and hoping to get it fixed in future version.